# How to create an interactive script that pauses a video, asks a question and then continues

Tags: video-streaming, interactive

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask (Please tell me a more appropriate forum if so) 
but have any of you seen a website where they play a video, pauses it, asks you a question, and then it continues the video, perhaps comparing the choice you choose to the correct one in the video.

Also have you seen any websites that use this? I have seen one that was something like "guess what happens" video. It also gives you points if you choose the right one. But I forgot the link, sorry.

Thanks guys.

Comment: This could probably be done in Flash, or if you prefer HTML5 with the video tag and some JavaScript. If you are looking for a specific options please update with the technology you are looking to use.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is fairly simple to do in Flash. I've done interactive video quizzes for several clients. Or did you have some specific web technology in mind that you need to use?